# Understanding the relation between countably paracompact and monotonically normal

Tags: general-topology, soft-question

Does monotonically normal imply countably paracompact? Thanks ahead:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does. This is essentially Theorem $2.3$ of Mary Ellen Rudin, *Dowker Spaces*, in the *Handbook of Set-Theoretic Topology*, K. Kunen & J.E. Vaughan, eds., North-Holland, 1984.